# add single quote and replace space with a comma

Tags: notepad++

I have rows/lines of data copied from Google spreadsheet into Notepad++ and I need to arrange so to put them in SQL codes (to add to tables rows). The copied data are lines of words (if you may), but they are like names, email, IDs. When copied into Notepad++, there can be a couple of spaces apart, more than one sometimes randomly. I need to add single a quote around each word, and separate them by a comma only.

What I copied into Notepad++:

```
CONTROL WHSE10018 xxx18@gmail.com John Smith    1PR10018 
CONTROL WHSE10002   kk222@hotmail.com   Kelly   John    1PR10002
```

What I want:

```
'CONTROL','WHSE10018','xxx18@gmail.com','John Smith,'1PR10018'
'CONTROL','WHSE10002','kk222@hotmail.com','Kelly','John','1PR10002'
```

Comment: So you want to add a quotes at the start end, and replace every run of whitespace with `','`?

Comment: Maybe the cells are TAB-separated when pasted into Notepad++. Use menu => **View** => **Show Symbol** => **Show Tab and Space**. Then replace TABs with `","`, plus adding the start and end quotes.

Comment: @AdrianHHH. Yes. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For Future readers, the solution was written by "AdrianHHH":

Maybe the cells are TAB-separated when pasted into Notepad++. Use menu => View => Show Symbol => Show Tab and Space. Then replace TABs with ",", plus adding the start and end quotes.

**Additional information:**

I think this might be the only possible solution, since the separator character SPACE is used in the name too.